# How to read a file using cat with Perl -e parameters?

Tags: linux, perl

I've set up a penetration testing VM and am trying to practice privilege escalation.

I'm currently trying to read a file. I do not have access to the user's home directory where the file is located but I have permissions to run `/usr/bin/perl` as the `user/admin`.

My understanding is that I could run the following command to essentially cat the file and see what's inside using the perl permissions granted to me but it doesn't seem to be working and gives no result back

```
james@linuxtest:~$ sudo -l
```

Matching Defaults entries for james on linuxtest:

```
env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin
```

User james may run the following commands on linuxtest:

```
(james2) /usr/bin/perl

james@linuxtest:~$ sudo -u james2 perl -e 'print 'cat /home/james/test.txt''
```

I expected the result to be the contents of the file or at least an error of some sort but no result. Am I making a stupid mistake here?

Comment: `'print 'cat /home/james/test.txt''` Try using double quotes inside the single quotes: `'print "cat /home/james/test.txt"'` If you are trying to run the `cat` command, use backquotes instead

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` for everything? I believe Kali autologins to `root`, so you are already super user. Kali aside, you don't use root unless you need to elevate privileges. Reading `/home/james/test.txt` from the `james` account does not need `sudo`.

Comment: Why not just `perl -e 'exec "/bin/bash"'`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you wanted

```
sudo -u james2 perl -e 'print `cat /home/james/test.txt`'
```

Backticks are used to execute a shell command and capture its output.

That's a weird way of doing

```
sudo -u james2 perl -e 'system "cat /home/james/test.txt"'
```

which is a weird way of doing

```
sudo -u james2 cat /home/james/test.txt
```

And since you're root, that's a weird way of doing

```
cat /home/james/test.txt
```